# List of shared files in NextCloud Web Interface

Tags: nextcloud

Not sure where to ask this question, here it is:
In the Web interface of NextCould, is it possible to display a list of all the files shared *with me* through *public links*? I've searched the NextCloud support pages but could not find anything regarding this feature.

Answer (score 0):

What about using files sidebar? There you have "Shares" and inside "Shared by link":

[Nextcloud files sidebar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXwr6.png)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but these are the files that *I* share. I would like to get the list of files that are shared *with me* by link.

Answer (score 0):

I think is no the correct concept. No links are shared with you when public links. So the shared links belong to the person who share, and there is no information about the other side. Then, you can see your "share by link" but never "shared with me by link".

Comment: In services such as Google Docs, for instance, when some shares a public link with you, the corresponding document appears among the other documents specifically shared with you. So, that makes sense from a UI perspective.